# notifyDataSetChanged removes last view

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-adapter

I have used Base Adapter to populate ListView and when i am removing an item from list and calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged then it is always deleting last View. As I read from other posts it instead of deleting last view it might be hiding last view because count of list decreases by 1.
Can anyone help me to display the required contents.

Here is my adapter class

```
public class ListOfFav extends BaseAdapter {

    TextView qid,ques,category;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> flightArray=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    private static final String TAG_QID = "qid";
    private static final String TAG_QUES = "question";
    private static final String TAG_CAT= "category";
    Context context;
    ListOfFav() {
    }

    public ListOfFav(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> flightList,Context c){
        Log.v("Constructor", String.valueOf(flightArray.size()));
        flightArray=flightList;
        context=c;
    }


    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return flightArray.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public  View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row;
        if(convertView==null||convertView.getTag()==null)
             row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_questions_main, parent, false);

        else
            row=convertView;

            qid=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tQid);
            ques= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tQuestion);
            category = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tCategory);

            qid.setText(flightArray.get(position).get(TAG_QID));
            ques.setText(flightArray.get(position).get(TAG_QUES));
            category.setText(flightArray.get(position).get(TAG_CAT));

            return (row);
    }
}
```

and i am updating it as:

```
for (HashMap<String, String> map : FavoriteList) {
        if (map.get(TAG_QID).equals(t.getText().toString())) 
            {
                 FavoriteList.remove(i);
                 favAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                 break;
            }
        i++;
 }
```

Comment: provide complete code, remove function code don't have complete code. But by your description it seems you are always deleting last item from FavoriteList that is why it removes last view always.

Comment: No i am not deleting the last item always. I am finding id in array list and deleting the corresponding item

Comment: how exactly you are removing your view ?  onClick Event of any Button in your Class or Adapter..

Comment: By swiping and selecting an item of the view of Adapter. Do i need to provide complete method?

Comment: In your method you have `FavouriteList.remove(i)` but where is `i` set? You're using a for each loop, so is it possible that `i` is set to the position at the end of the list prior to it reaching that statement?

Comment: 'i' is initialised to 0 in starting and also i have used log to again traverse through whole array list of hash map to check for the remaining id's and it gives me the correct result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by calling FavouriteListView.setAdapter(favAdapter) after notifying array adapter that list associated with it has been changed i.e. by refreshing the list view adapter.